# Change focus if input field is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'll make function if the focus of input field is blank, focus will be change to other input field, it's possible if using jquery?

I've trying but doesn't work.

Here's HTML Code:

```
<form>
  Username:<br />
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="notblank" /><br />
  <br />
  Password:<br />
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="notblank" />
</form>
```

Here's Jquery Code:

```
$('#password').each(function(){
  if($(this).val() == ''){
    $('#username').focus();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Here's [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4m5fg/547/).

Thanks.

Comment: I think you want to user can't write password if username is empty. Also when `#password` focused, if `#username` is empty, js should focus on `#username`. Is that right?

Comment: change `each` to `focus` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("input").on("input",function(){
        
        if($(this).val() == '')
            
            $("input").not(this).focus();
            
    })
    
})
```

```html
<form>
  Username:<br />
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="notblank" />
  <br /><br />
  Password:
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="notblank" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**change only when #password is blank focus change to #username ,**

**Try this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#password").on("input",function(){
        
        if($(this).val() == '')
            
            $("#username").focus();
            
    })
    
})
```

```html
<form>
  Username:<br />
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="notblank" />
  <br /><br />
  Password:
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="notblank" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but, why if `#username` field is blank, focus changed to `#password` field ?

Comment: when #username is blank focus change to another input , it is  #password.

Comment: you can to change only when #password is blank focus change to #username ?

Answer (score 0):

`each` - for many inputs with id 'password'. You should listen eg. `keyup` instead of.

```
$('#password').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val() == ''){
    $('#username').focus();
    return false;
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4m5fg/549/

Comment: it's work bro, but the problem is, when focus have change to other input field

Comment: Mb I don't undestand. Another input clears password-input and then need to set focus to username field?

http://jsfiddle.net/4m5fg/551/

Comment: sorry that was not yet complete comment, I mean `it's work bro, but the problem is, when focus have change to other input field with tab button, it's will be back to #username field`